# Какие существуют информеры погоды с собственным API?

Tags: api, поиск-api, weather

Подскажите сервис, от которого требуется показывать данные на текущий момент о:

- температуре
- осадках
- скорости и направлении ветра
- времени восхода и заката

Больше ничего не требуется. Желательно, чтобы все это фильтровалось по параметрам, так как лишние данные ничем не помогут.

Пробовал Яндекс API, но:

1. на сайте не нашел их документации
2. в списке городов нет моего города (если взять ближайший, то данные все равно немного отличаются).

Почти так же неприемлем парсинг целых страниц с данными о погоде или хотя бы информеры...

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/weather-data#current

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал вам посмотреть в сторону wunderground.com или forecast.io. При должных знаниях можно все настроить.

Это - пример работы [forecast](https://github.com/ZeevG/python-forecast.io/blob/master/tests/test_forecastio.py)

```
import os
import unittest
import responses
import requests

import forecastio

from nose.tools import raises
from datetime import datetime


class EndToEnd(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
self.api_key = os.environ.get("API")

    self.lat = 52.370235
    self.lng = 4.903549

    self.time = datetime(2015, 2, 27, 6, 0, 0)
def test_with_time(self):

    forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(
        self.api_key, self.lat,
        self.lng, time=self.time
    )
    self.assertEqual(forecast.response.status_code, 200)

def test_without_time(self):
```

Как видно все довольно просто и понятно.

Comment: Постарайтесь публиковать более полные ответы, добавьте пример кода, приведите информацию из документации. Рассмотрите плюсы и минусы приведённых вами сервисов.

Comment: какой максимальный набор данных могут возвращать первый и второй на free?

Comment: У Форкаста 1к запросов бесплатно в день заявлено.